# How do I create objects in python when iterating through elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, oop, object

I am trying to pass elements in a list to a class to create an object in Python.  When I, later, use that same list to try and recall that object I get the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'.

I've been using Python for a while, but new to OOP.  Wondering if this is about the scope of an object>

```
class SwimmingWithTheFishes:
    def __init__(self, typeofshark):
        self.name = typeofshark

    def __str__(self):
        return f"This is the method shark: {self.name}"

    def reporting(self, shark):
        name = shark.name
        print(f"This is a method shark: {name}")

    def print_return(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


def main():
    # sharklist = [{"name": "mako"}, {"name": "hammerhead"}, {"name": "greatwhite"}, {"name": "reef"}]
    sharklist = ["mako", "hammerhead", "greatwhite", "reef"]

    for typeofshark in sharklist:
        typeofshark = SwimmingWithTheFishes(typeofshark)
        print(f"Heavens above, that's no fish: {typeofshark.name}")
        typeofshark.reporting(typeofshark)

    for shark in sharklist:
        print(SwimmingWithTheFishes.print_return(shark))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `sharklist` is a list of strings, so `shark` is a string. You're passing that string to `print_return`, which obviously cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print_return` is a method of `SwimmingWithTheFishes`, so you should instantiate `SwimmingWithTheFishes` with `shark` instead so that `self` will become an object of `SwimmingWithTheFishes` for `self.name` to work in `print_return`.

Change:

```
print(SwimmingWithTheFishes.print_return(shark))
```

to:

```
print(SwimmingWithTheFishes(shark).print_return())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are iterating over a list and assign to the current variable, you do *not* change the value in the list, you only change that local variable.

E.g.

```
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> for i in l:
...     i += 1
... 
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

---

To modify the list, you should create a new list since you can run into problems if you modify the list that you iterate over. This new list could be called something like `sharks` - where the elements contain the class instances.

Finally, you also have a misunderstanding with methods... You do not need to pass in a reference to the object every time you call a method on an instance. The `self` argument to the method function automatically takes the value of the instance which you call the method from.

This makes the final code:

```
class SwimmingWithTheFishes:
    def __init__(self, typeofshark):
        self.name = typeofshark

    def __str__(self):
        return f"I am a {self.name} shark."

    def reporting(self):
        print(f"This is a {self.name} shark method.") 


def main():
    # shark_types = [{"name": "mako"}, {"name": "hammerhead"}, {"name": "greatwhite"}, {"name": "reef"}]
    shark_types = ["mako", "hammerhead", "greatwhite", "reef"]
    sharks = []

    for type_ in shark_types:
        shark = SwimmingWithTheFishes(type_)
        sharks.append(shark)
        print(f"Heavens above, that's no fish: {shark.name}")
        shark.reporting()

    for shark in sharks:
        print(shark)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Which gives:

```
Heavens above, that's no fish: mako
This is a mako shark method.
Heavens above, that's no fish: hammerhead
This is a hammerhead shark method.
Heavens above, that's no fish: greatwhite
This is a greatwhite shark method.
Heavens above, that's no fish: reef
This is a reef shark method.
I am a mako shark.
I am a hammerhead shark.
I am a greatwhite shark.
I am a reef shark.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense.  Appreciated.